# How to set a visibility of TextBlock bound to a ListBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock, listboxitem

How can I set a TextBlock visibility inside a ListBox. For example

```
<Grid>
   <ListBox Name="myList">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <TextBloxk Name="txtBlock1" Text="{Binding} First Name">
             <TextBloxk Name="txtBlock2" Text="{Binding} Last Name">
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

At run time, I want to set the visibility of either textblocks to either Visible or Collapsed.

How can I do that, or can I?

Comment: At runtime I want to do like `txtBlock1.visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) (or other, custom converter) to change the Visibility according to binding value.

Comment: Is it only according to the binding value? For instance, I want to set the visibility of the TextBlock based on the application settings (IsolatedStorageSettings) `ShowFirstName = settings["ShowFN"]...if (ShowFirstName != true)...txtBlock1.visible = False` Something like that

Comment: If you want to do that in XAML using converter it has to be a binding value (but not necessary from the current ListBoxItem - check Binding ElementName).

Comment: I think the resource is not available anymore. (http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation) there's an error.

Comment: I used this approach, and it works... but for dummies like me (who are new to WP7 and C#), these two links are very useful. 1.http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6758589c3549#src%2fCaliburn.Micro.Silverlight%2fBooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs (Complete class, just copy paste :). 2. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx (Application in XAML). Thanks, MarcinJuraszek!

Answer (score 0):

Use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) if you need to iterate over each of the items in the ListBox. Or, re-bind ListBox to the new set of data and use MarcinJuraszek's suggestion on using a Converter (definitely an easier choice :))

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I used his approach :)